# How does Google mail achieve rtf in textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I am intended to develop a rich input textarea similar to Google mail. Any ideal or resource to share? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+rich+text+input

Comment: wow, I get nearly zilch with a view source of mail.google.com

Comment: I'd be kind of interested in any sort of technical analysis of exactly what Google is doing in the HTML/CSS/DOM to accomplish this sort of thing, if anyone has that available (GMail seems to crash my Firebug)

Answer (score 7):

My suggestion is to use [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) it is a great Rich Text Box.  Yahoo also has a [really great Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/) (which has been deprecated).

Comment: And the verdict is......it's brilliant! Very easy to use, and works with Macs too, which helps my colleagues out a great deal.

Comment: I should say, it was TinyMCE I was using.

Answer (score 4):

These are *not* textareas, btw - they are IFRAMEs holding full HTML managed by the editor code. I also recommend FCKeditor - very configurable and easily integrated. You can write your code using textareas, make a javascript call and those textareas go hidden and the IFRAME gets injected in place. Upon submit the html gets copied back in the textarea. so really don't need to do much...

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what google uses, but I've used [FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/) and it worked out great.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the ContentEditable tag. And also have a look at [Squire on gihub](https://github.com/neilj/Squire) which is an open source rich text editor that is very lightweight and flexible (used in opera's mail client)

The editors given in the other answers are very heavy and come with their own (outdated, bloated) UI components.